# How to Disable SSLv2 for Apache httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl, mod-ssl, pci-dss

I just tested my site on https://www.ssllabs.com/ and it said SSLv2 is insecure and I should disable that along with weak Cipher Suites.

How can I disable that? I tried the following but it isn’t working.

1. Went to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` by ftp. Added

   ```
   SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT
   ```
2. Connected to server by putty and gave `service httpd restart` command.

But still its showing unsecure on the site. How can I Fix it? My server is Plesk 10.3.1 CentOS.
There are 3-4 sites on the same server.

Comment: A few years ago I had problem while renewing an ssl certificate. The new configuration was ignored, even after an apache restart.

Stopping apache then starting apache solved the problem.

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU - I rebooted the whole server , Still no luck

Answer (score 10):

Change SSLProtocol and SSLCipherSuite lines to,

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1 -SSLv2
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
```

Reload your apache for the configuration to take effect.

The *SSLHonorCipherOrder On* will try the ciphers in the order it is specified.

Above configuration passes the check on ssllabs.com except for TLS version. My CentOS 6 only supports TLS 1.0 because of OpenSSL 1.0.0. OpenSSL 1.0.1 supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

Do you have any load balancer or proxy in front of your apache?

Comment: I Added the lines that you mentioned above , But still it doesnt work . When I check on `www.ssllabs.com `it still shows that its enabled . 

I am Unaware about ` load balancer or proxy in front of apache` , How can I check this ? I'll let you know the details what ever you need to know.

Comment: However when I run this , I get an Error . So it seems its disabled ,but the site isn't showing it.

`openssl s_client -ssl2 -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
21731:error:1407F0E5:SSL routines:SSL2_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s2_pkt.c:428:
]0;root@u15341216:~[root@u15341216 ~]# `

Comment: It could be coming from your loadbalancer or proxy from some other backend application. Without much details on your setup/architecture, it is hard to debug.  The configuration I mentioned, works for my apache that serves SSL directly and ssllabs.com gives me a rating of 88.

Comment: So I should Disable the load balancer , If its there on the system ? How can I find out if its installed on not?

Comment: If apache listens on port *:80 and you server has the public ip corresponding to your website, there is no loadbalancer. Also check dns records for round robin.

Comment: Could you post your apache configuration files?

Comment: Adi, did this work for you? Could you post your apache config files?

Comment: @Chida = No . Its still not working .
Do you need the ssl.conf file ?

Comment: @Chida- I can email them , Can I know your email Id ?

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU - I uploaded the Files at http://adimathur.com/ssl.zip

Comment: @Chida -I uploaded the Files at http://adimathur.com/ssl.zip

Comment: It worked for my CentOS server and the grade now is A from ssllabs.com. Thank you, Chida!!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to make sure that there isn't another `SSLProtocol` or `SSLCiperSuite` direcive anywhere in your Apache config that's overriding the one you just added.

If you can't find it, try adding those two to your SSL vhost rather than `ssl.conf`.  This will help ensure that the correct ones are the last ones applied.

Comment: There isnt any duplicate entry in the file .

How can I check in SSL Vhost ? Where is this file placed ? (Am new here )

Comment: Using PuTTY, `grep -r SSLProtocol /etc/httpd` should find any duplicates.  As for the SSL vhost, I don't know where Plesk puts them but it will probably be with all the other vhosts.  A recursive grep for `VirtualHost`, `SSLCertificateFile` or the documentroot will probably do the trick.

Comment: `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/conf/vhost_ssl.conf`  & `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/conf/vhost.conf`

In both the files I have Added `SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM` still isnt working :/

Answer (score 0):

The one worked for me

```
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH"
```

Try this one.

Comment: Are you using Plesk? Please elaborate on how your situation matches that described in the original question.

Answer (score -2):

To disable SSL in Centos6.x Just run following command:

yum remove mod_ssl

Then

service httpd reload

To enable SSL again again install "mod_ssl" package like:

yum install mod_ssl

Then

service httpd reload

Comment: I think the user only wanted to remove SSL v2.